# Cronjob con performed

Tags: oracle

I am trying to export with datapump command for backup purpose runs in terminal, but could not be run in cron.

```
00 09 * * * /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/expdp user/pass schemas=schema directory=directory dumpfile=expdpbakup.dmp logfile=expdplog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing the command directly in cron better create sample script and source there your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to set variables like ORACLE_BASE, PATH, ORACLE_SID:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/expdp user/pass schemas=schema directory=directory dumpfile=expdpbakup.dmp logfile=expdplog.log
```

and add in cron:

```
0 9 * * * /path/to/the/script.sh
```

Comment: Even can not run, error appeared as: 
UDE-00013: Message 13 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UDE
UDE-00019: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

Comment: @AbdulSalam, you can set the variables directly in the script or add them from the file where they are set